# System.indexoutofrangeexception: 'cannot find column 1'

Tags: c#, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I have a program to parse a CSV file from local filesystem to a specified SQL Server table.
Now when i execute the program i get error :
**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 1'**  exception on the line where i the program attempts to populate the datatable.

On closer inspection the error shows that its emanating from row number 3 as shown on this link :
[CSV_ERROR](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FOUavsf_D_1H5M2MGf6_v8kFDCNs_kYG/view?usp=sharing)

This is how i am reading and saving the CSV file :

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var absPath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\MastercardSurveillance\fbc_mc_all_cards.csv";
       
        ProcessFile();    

        void ProcessFile()
        {
            string realPath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\CSV";
            string appLog = "CSVERRORS";

            var logPath = realPath + Convert.ToString(appLog) + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd -MM-yy") + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(logPath))
            {
                File.Create(logPath).Dispose();
            }
            var dt = GetDATATable();
            if (dt == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {                
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logPath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("No rows imported after reading file " + absPath);
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                }
                return;
            }
            ClearData();
            InsertDATA();
        }
        DataTable GetDATATable()
        {
            var FilePath = absPath;
            string TableName = "Cards";
            string realPath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\CSV";
            string appLog = "CSVERRORS";

            var logPath = realPath + Convert.ToString(appLog) + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd -MM-yy") + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(logPath))
            {
                File.Create(logPath).Dispose();
            }
                var dt = new DataTable(TableName);
            using (var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(FilePath))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                var readFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                if (readFields == null)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logPath))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Could not read header fields for file " + FilePath);
                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                    
                    return null;
                }
                foreach (var dataColumn in readFields.Select(column => new DataColumn(column, typeof(string)) { AllowDBNull = true, DefaultValue = string.Empty }))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    var data = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logPath))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("Could not read fields on line {0} for file {1}", csvReader.LineNumber, FilePath));
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.Close();
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    var dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[i]))
                        {
                            dr[i] = data[i];
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
         void ClearData()
         {               
            string SqlSvrConn = @"Server=XXXXXX-5QFK4BL\MSDEVOPS;Database=McardSurveillance;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlSvrConn))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                // Truncate the live table
                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(_truncateLiveTableCommandText, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
              
         }
        void InsertDATA()
        {
            string SqlSvrConn = @"Server=XXXXXX-5QFK4BL\MSDEVOPS;Database=McardSurveillance;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
            DataTable table = GetDATATable();
            using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlSvrConn))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Cards";
                for (var count = 0; count < table.Columns.Count; count++)
                {
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(count, count);
                }
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
        }

    }
```

How can i identify and possibly exclude the extra data columns being returned from the CSV file?

It appears there is a mismatch between number of columns in datatable and number of columns being read from the CSV file.
Im not sure however how i can account for this with my logic. For now i did not want to switch to using a CSV parse package but rather i need insight on how i can remove the extra column or rather ensure that the splitting takes account of all possible dubious characters.
For clarity i have a copy of the CSV file here :

[CSV_FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bPFf8aGAkM1UAOhfCq6hUV_rexd7GfpP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have been getting an error whenever i open the CSV file  in Excel that says : The file format and extension of '' dont match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Could this be a possible reason also?

Comment: Maybe. Is it column1 or column 1 ?